# How to verify a react-google-recaptcha v2 using jest while testing a React-Typescript App?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-google-recaptcha

So basically I've a Login form with two input fields (password, email) and a react-google-recaptcha. My use case is simple. *Test if the submit button is disabled if the input fields are empty and recaptcha is not verified. Enable it only when input fields contain data and recaptcha is verified.*

Below is the code that I wrote and I know I did something wrong with recaptcha verification in test file.

I've gone through existing answers in Stack Overflow for example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69017515/how-to-account-for-google-recaptcha-in-jest-unit-test-with-nextjs-api) but facing problem implementing the same.

**Login.tsx**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

import ReCAPTCHA from "react-google-recaptcha";

const Login = () => {
  const [creds, setCreds] = useState({
    email: "",
    pw: "",
  });
  const [isCaptchaVerified, setIsCaptchaVerified] = useState(false);

  const handleCaptchaChange = (value): void => {
    if (value !== null) setIsCaptchaVerified(true);
    else setIsCaptchaVerified(false);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <input
        data-testid="email-testid"
        type="email"
        name="email"
        value={creds.email}
        onChange={(e) => {
          setCreds({
            email: e.target.value,
            pw: creds.pw,
          });
        }}
      />
      <input
        data-testid="pw-testid"
        type="password"
        name="password"
        value={creds.pw}
        onChange={(e) => {
          setCreds({
            pw: e.target.value,
            email: creds.email,
          });
        }}
      />
      <ReCAPTCHA
        data-testid="login-recaptcha"
        sitekey={siteKey}
        onChange={handleCaptchaChange}
      />
    <button data-testid="submit-testid" disabled={!isCaptchaVerified || !creds.pw || 
    !creds.email}>
        Submit
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Login;
```

**Login.test.tsx**

```
test("test if button is disabled untill captcha is verified",()=> {
    const loginRecaptcha = screen.findByTestId('login-recaptcha');
    const emailField = screen.findByTestId('email-testid');
    const pwField = screen.findByTestId('pw-testid');
    const submitButton = screen.findByTestId('submit-testid');

    expect(submitButton).toBeDisabled();

    fireEvent.change(emailField, { target: { value: "user@test.com" } });
    fireEvent.change(pwField, { target: { value: "user@1234" } });
    fireEvent.click(loginRecaptcha);

    expect(submitButton).not.toBeDisabled();
})
```